# RESTfully creating object graphs

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to design a RESTful API for creating object graphs. For example, think of an eCommerce API, where resources have the following relationships:

**Order (the main object)**

- Has-many Addresses
- Has-many Order Line items (what does the order consist of)
- Has-many Payments
- Has-many Contact Info

The Order resource usually makes sense along with it's associations. In isolation, it's just a dumb container with no business significance. However, each of the associated objects has a life of it's own and may need to be manipulated independently, eg. editing the shipping address of an order, changing the contact info against an order, removing a line-item from an order *after* it has been placed, etc.

There are two options for designing the API:

- The Order API endpoint intelligently creates itself AND its associated resources by processing "nested resource" in the content sent to `POST /orders`
- The Order resource only creates itself and the client has to make follow-up POST requests to newly created endpoints, like `POST /orders/123/addresses`, `PUT /orders/123/line-items/987`, etc.

While the second option is simpler to implement at the server-side, it makes the client do extra work for 80% of the use-cases.

The first option has the following open questions:

- How does one communicate the URL for the newly created resource? The `Location` header can communicate only one URL, however the server would've potentially created multiple resources.
- How does one deal with errors? What if one of the associons has an error? Do we reject the entire object graph? How is that error communicated to the client?

What's the RESTful + pragmatic way of dealing with this?

Comment: Does "usually makes sense" mean that an Order *can* exist without the other Resources or not? Would the Resources be in an invalid state in between two steps of option 2?

Comment: In 80% of the cases data for associations will be available at the time of Order creation. However, in 20% of the cases, we *may* want to store a partial object in the DB to be updated & processed at a later stage. For example, we may want to skip the payment info and add it later.

Answer (score 1):

How I handle this is the first way. You should not assume that a client will make all the requests it needs to. Create all the entities on the one request.

Depending on your use case you may also want to enforce an 'all-or-nothing' approach in creating the entities; ie, if something falls, everything rolls back. You can do this by using a transaction on your database (which you also can't do if everything is done through separate requests). Determining if this is the behavior you want is very specific to your situation. For instance, if you are creating an order statement you may which to employ this (you dont want to create an order that's missing items), however if you are uploading photos it may be fine.

For returning the links to the client, I always return a JSON object. You could easily populate this object with links to each of the resources created. This way the client can determine how to behave after a successful post.

Comment: The benefit of having a DB transaction is there, but there's an added complication of communicating error messages. What's the RESTful approach for communicating error messages in a particular object of an object graph?

Comment: Its up to you, as long as you document how your API is behaving. Perhaps in the response JSON object I mentioned you include the error information instead of the links?

Comment: Is there a de-facto standard/convention for returning errors in RESTful APIs? Specifically when creation of an object-graph fails?

Comment: I do not know, however I do not believe so. As I said, I tend to to return an object with an 'error' field if an error occurs, however if you document what you are going to return it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Both options can be implemented RESTful. You ask:

> How does one communicate the URL for the newly created resource? The `Location` header can communicate only one URL, however the server would've potentially created multiple resources.

This would be done the same way you communicate `links`s to other Resources in the `GET` case.  Use `link` elements or what ever your method is to embed the URL of a Resource into a Representation.